# Integration of Here map in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, here-maps-rest

I am creating a react native mobile app. I am trying to implement
   Here map API in my react-native app. There are options like [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) and [react-native-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps), but these libraries require API keys of
   Google or Mapbox. Is there any such library by which I can build the app using only Here map APIs?

Comment: are you found a solution?